# Error getting the associated data in a query inside a custom class. CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I´m trying to load the associated data in a query within my custom class CstmGroupsClass, but I get the error "The Books association is not defined on Libraries". The only way it works is writing loadModel('CstmLibraries') in the controller and changing the alias to the relationships of the models to the originals, for example hasMany('Books',...) to hasMany('CstmBooks',...). But I need to be able to execute the query inside the custom class and in it I can´t use loadModel() and tableRegistry does not solve the problem.

Thanks for the help.

**CstmGroupsClass.php**

```php
class CstmGroupsClass {

    protected $CstmGroups;

    function __construct() {        
        $this->CstmGroups = TableRegistry::get('CstmGroups');
    }

    public function listGroups($contain = []) { //Value of $contain: ['Libraries','Libraries.Books']       
        $listGroups = $this->CstmGroups->find()->contain($contain);
        return $listGroups->execute(); /* <= Here the error is produced */       
    }
}
```

**CstmGroupsController.php**

```php
class CstmGroupsController extends AppController {

    private $cstmGroupsClass;

    public function initialize() {  
        $this->cstmGroupsClass = new CstmGroupsClass();
    }

    public function listGroups() {

        $responseListGroups = $this->cstmGroupsClass->listGroups(['Libraries','Libraries.Books']);

        $this->set(compact('responseListGroups'));
    }
}
```

**CstmGroupsTable.php**

```php
class CstmGroupsTable extends Table {

    public $prefix = 'cstm_';

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable($this->prefix.'groups'); //final name: cstm_groups
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasOne('Libraries', [
            'className' => $this->prefix.'libraries', //final name: cstm_libraries
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**CstmLibrariesTable.php**

```php
class CstmLibrariesTable extends Table
{
    public $prefix = 'cstm_';

    public function initialize(array $config){
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable($this->prefix.'libraries'); //final name: cstm_libraries
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->hasOne('Groups',[
            'className' => $this->prefix.'groups', //final name: cstm_groups
            'foreignKey' => 'library_id'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('Books', [
            'className' => $this->prefix.'books', //final name: cstm_books
            'foreignKey' => 'library_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**CstmBooksTable.php**

```php
class CstmBooksTable extends Table {

    public $prefix = 'cstm_';

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable($this->prefix.'books'); //final name: cstm_books
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Libraries', [
            'className' => $this->prefix.'libraries', //final name: cstm_libraries
            'foreignKey' => 'library_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that your table names can all start with `cstm_`, but the class names in your associations should be camel-cased, e.g. your "final name" for the `className` keys should look like `CstmLibraries`, not `cstm_libraries`.

Comment: I don't know how I did not realize that. It works correctly now. Really thanks!